# packaging issues with a function that uses arules

Tags: r, package, match, arules

I'm using R and trying to assemble a bunch of functions into a package. One of the function uses the package arules to mine rules from a dataset, subset them and get other interest measures.

I'm having problem with the line that subsets them.

```
rules <- apriori(trainingTrans, parameter = list(support = 0.005, confidence = 0.0, maxlen = 6)  
rulesCases <- subset(rules, subset = rhs %in% "event")
```

The functions works outside of the package as long as I've loaded arules, but doesn't work in the package whether I've set arules as a Depends, an Imports, or had the function call it with library(arules). The error displayed is 'match' requires vector arguments. I thought Arules has its own version of match to get around that, I've tried arules::match(rhs,"event"), but I still have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that it does not find the correct version of %in%. Possibly this works:

```
rulesCases <- subset(rules, subset = arules::"%in%"(rhs, "event"))
```

This should be not necessary if you import `arules`, but there seems to be something weird going on. I hope this will be resolved in a future release of arules.

Comment: Still no luck. :( When I looked in the documentation, match was another way to right "%in%" which is why I tried with specifying the package first-arules::match (rhs,"event"), but I'm just not having any luck. I tried it with your line instead, but still no go :(. I'm stumped.

Comment: This is weird! What version of arules do you have installed (call sessionInfo() after loading your package).

Comment: I'm using arules_1.1-9

Comment: You probably should consider updating to a current version (1.3-1). You probably also need to update R.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in my package and be able to fix it :

The syntax `subset(rules, subset = arules::"%in%"(rhs, "event"))` forces to use the correct version of `%in%` in the package, as Michael Hahsler noticed

But `rhs` is no more related with `rules` so it needed to be re-precised using `rules@rhs`

So the correct syntax should be `subset(rules, subset = arules::"%in%"(rules@rhs, "event"))`

It do the job for my package, with the DESCRIPTION file containing

```
LinkingTo: arules
Imports: arules
```

And no further uses of `library(arules)`.